# Would this site be open to adopting WindowsPhone in 5 years?

Tags: discussion, scope

In 5 years windows phone will be vintage and although updates have stalled at this point would this site be open to taking windows phone?

[This has been discussed briefly on the other site.](https://windowsphone.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384/congratulations-youre-no-longer-in-beta)

This would bring more traction to one site.

Right now the question ratio is quite poor at [Windows phone](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/20757/windows-phone) and dropping.

And [retro computing](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/94441/retrocomputing) it’s better.

This is some [basic Q&A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/342646/merging-technical-sites-with-stack-overflow) about merging sites.

Comment: "The good thing with history is there's an endless supply of it" ;)

Answer (score 6):

The Windows Phone Stack Exchange was [archived today](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383855/336163). With questions about Windows Phone no longer having a clear home anywhere on the network, it might be time to step up and start accepting them.

Comment: Windows 10 Mobile was end-of-lifed by Microsoft on December 10, 2019, so it feels a bit soon to call it "retro". The content of the windows phone site wasn't retro at the time it was active, so we're not talking about importing retrocomputing content so much as importing stale Q&A. People looking for support have other options, e.g. https://www.reddit.com/r/windowsphone/ .

Comment: I don't think I'd call it retro, but I've got a soft spot for Windows Phone that sits very close to my soft spot for BeOS. It was quite unique, with more customisation than iOS and a a more cohesive UI than Android. Despite not being "retro" in the computer sense, I'd argue it is most definitely retro in the arena of phone hardware and software.

Answer (score 5):

[I agree with OmarL](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/945/6659). Just because some site is fading it doesn't get vintage - especially not with RC.SE, as, despite the generic liberal handling, our definitions are made for easy exclusion, not automatic inclusion. Then again, we do accept rather fringe areas as well - various arcade questions might give an example.

Then again, browsing the questions at [WindowsPhone.SE](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/) makes me think that these support orientates questions might draw a quite negative response from our core audience.

**Bottom line: I do not think that merging the sites will be beneficial for either.**

Answer (score 4):

Don't think so. Retrocomputing is about technology much older than Windows Phone.

> In 5 years windows phone will be vintage

Not really; it's just another discontinued platform. As such it has the same status as the PS4 will have.

Comment: You already have windows mobile but I see interesting.

Comment: As a sidenote, games are still being released (often for both PS4 and PS5).